# Firestore Event Listeners conflict within Containers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Inside my application I have listeners listening to firestore documents if any changes occurs, the issue occurs when the application is deployed to AWS/OS/GCP and the pod size is greater than 1. With a pod size of greater than 1 that means I have more than 1 listener listening to the same object, so when a change occurs I have now these multiple event changes that I am attempting to process.

At a high level, what can I implement to ensure that only 1 change is processed even though the same listener is triggered multiple times in parallel (based on # of pods active).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're running into can't really be avoided easily with your current architecture.

You should consider using [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs) instead to trigger on changes to documents.  [Firestore triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore) will only execute once per document change (barring a rare duplicate event, which you must de-dup on your own), yet scale up to 1000 concurrent server instances to handle load.  You can then do something to signal your application afterward if needed.

Comment: Considering even if I have a unique ID this would be the case? Another solution being using some sort of queue activemq, rabbitmq, etc.

Comment: So cloud functions to ensure that the event is processed at once minimum, then have that cloud function do a POST to my service/application. Got it.